# "RDS is currently busy" and I can not log in to the server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, administrator, remote-access, windows-server-2016

After 2 users have connected (except myself) to the server with RemoteDesktopServices, then I can not log in until the server restarts.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATx2n.jpg)

It gives the error shown on the screenshot.

Everyone in the office can log in except me.  But when the server is restarted, I can log in too.

What I already tried:

- Task Manager: disconnect other users as admin from another account.
- sfc /scannow on cmd as admin
- `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client " "   Name: RDGClientTransport "` -> I didn't find anything as that name

Comment: Are you able to connect to this RDP Server using your account from other machine when you can't connect from yours desktop?

Comment: @mariaczi I think I did not test what you said that now. I may have applied it on other machines at the office as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause

At least since Server 2008, there is a maximum of two concurrent RDP sessions allowed. If you've got the system virtualized, you can have three sessions at once: two via RDP, one via direct console login. Normally, if the other users log out completely, the slot should become available again.

This means that while you can have dozens of people who can be authorized to RDP on the machine, only two can do so at the very same time.

If you need more people on the machine on the same time, you've got what Microsoft now calls a Remote Session Host, formerly known as a terminalserver.

## Solution

As soon as you need more than two people at the same time, you've got what Microsoft considers a Session Host (formerly Terminalserver), so to be able to have more concurrent users, you will need to install the [session host role service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2833839/guidelines-for-installing-the-remote-desktop-session-host-role-service) on the machine.

You will also need to buy additional RDS User Cals to be properly licensed afterwards.

Reference: [Technet](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4d9a518-210d-40e9-8638-77e23110cfb3/more-than-2-remote-desktop-sessions?forum=windowshpcitpros)

Comment: "Normally, if the other users log out completely, the slot should become available again."      -> YES but I can't you know.    I need another opportunity to fix this without adding host role

Comment: What exactly are you saying? You need more than two users at the same time without upgrading to session host? That's simply not possible.

Comment: No I mean there must be an another way to fix this issue. The problem continues since the beginning of 2018.

Comment: What else can you say me about fixing this error?

Comment: What is the error for you? The message on the screenshot? That is **intentional behaviour**. If you need more users, then what you've got is a terminal server from microsofts point of view.

Comment: So my best option to do not see this log on issue anymore is adding new user ?? (but you're getting a reference from technet, so you not sure ?)

Comment: Dude I need a permanent solution

Comment: _Dude_, i've already given you the answer in the very first post. I've updated it for more clarity, I don't think I can explain it any better.

Comment: Ok I will check and maybe do it. Thanks for your best support on this! AND I will let you know the situation in this time.

Comment: Alright, good luck to you.

Comment: How did it turn out? If you haven't found a way around this, you might mark it as answered.